# Netsuite: Push or pull PDF template via API

Tags: netsuite, vscode-extensions, suitescript

For now, I copy all the PDF template in my IDE to save it, use versionning and formatting.
I spend my time to copy the PDF template that I'm updating in Netsuite.
I would like to be able to customize all the pdf template in my IDE and send it via REST API to Netsuite.
Is it possible?